# Transfer variables between Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I’ve just started to learn Vue.js and need help.
I have two components, the first one is not a parent for the second.

I need to transfer a variable from one component to another. I’ve tried to use “props” - bad idea

Maybe someone knows how to avoid this “parent” restriction

Comment: You can use a "Store" to share data reactively between components. For example [VueX Store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

Answer (score 1):

At first be sure you have read and understood the Vue Docs about Components.

- [Components Basics](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html)
- [Props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html)
- [Component v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html)

Check also

- [Vue Tutorial: Step 11. Components](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-11)
- [Vue Examples: Simple Component](https://vuejs.org/examples/#simple-component)

Here are some answers that could help you with examples:

- [VUE.JS 3 Changing boolean value of one sibling component from
  another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75286926/2487565)
- [Share data between two child components Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213174/share-data-between-two-child-components-vue-js)